# type '(DateTime) => String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter, datetime, flutter-text, flutter-datetime-picker

i am creating a laundry app but i am seeing this error saying cant use datatime in string. i have provided every code which have datetime in text involved and provided run error. here is the additional code of 2 classes which uses datetime in string, still im facing this issue please help [[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEIfD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04mlo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFdNH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGxNi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QBwk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cauzQ.png)

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; // Import DateFormat for date formatting
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:laundry_app/config/app_format.dart'; // Assuming AppFormat contains date and currency formatting methods
import 'package:laundry_app/data/model/laundry.dart'; // Assuming Laundry model is defined in this file

class DetailLaundry extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailLaundry({Key? key, required this.laundry}) : super(key: key);
  final Laundry laundry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      children: [
        dataText('Customer', laundry.customerName!),
        dataText('Status', laundry.status!),
        dataText('Queue Date', AppFormat.date(laundry.queueDate!)),
        dataText('Weight', '${laundry.weight} Kg'),
        dataText('Price', AppFormat.currency(laundry.price!)),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        if (laundry.startDate != null || laundry.endDate != null) ...[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              if (laundry.startDate != null)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                  child: Text('Washing (Start)'),
                ),
              if (laundry.endDate != null)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                  child: Text('Done (End)'),
                ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              if (laundry.startDate != null)
                Text(
                  laundry.startDate != null
                      ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(laundry.startDate!)
                      : 'No Date',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),

              if (laundry.endDate != null)
                Text(
                  laundry.endDate != null
                      ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(laundry.endDate!)
                      : 'No Date',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget dataText(String title, String body) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(title),
        SizedBox(height: 5), // Use SizedBox for spacing
        Text(
          body,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5), // Use SizedBox for spacing
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WhereStatusPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WhereStatusPage({Key? key, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  final String status;
  
  @override
  State<WhereStatusPage> createState() => _WhereStatusPageState();
}

class _WhereStatusPageState extends State<WhereStatusPage> {
  final cWhereStatus = Get.put(CWhereStatus());

  void refresh() {
    cWhereStatus.setList(widget.status);
  }

  // Calling the function with a DateTime object

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    refresh();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: DView.appBarLeft(widget.status),
      body: GetBuilder<CWhereStatus>(
        builder: (_) {
          if (_.list.isEmpty) {
            return DView.empty();
          }

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _.list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Laundry laundry = _.list[index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.to(() => DetailPage(laundry: laundry))?.then((value) {
                        if (value ?? false) {
                          refresh();
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 18.0,
                      child: Text('${index + 1}'),
                    ),
                    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                    title: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(laundry.customerName!),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          '${laundry.id}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          laundry.queueDate != null
                              ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                  .format(laundry.queueDate!)
                              : 'No Date',
                        ),
                        Text(
                          laundry.queueDate != null
                              ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                  .format(laundry.queueDate!)
                              : 'No Date',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}`

> import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class AppFormat {
  static String date(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('EEEE , d MMM yyyy').format(date as DateTime);
  }

  static String time(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dateTime);
  }

  static String currency(double price) {
    return NumberFormat.currency(
      decimalDigits: 2,
      symbol: '\$',
      locale: 'en_US',
    ).format(price);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share AppFormat class? And the exact line (84) where the error is triggered.

Comment: Please share the app_format.dart file

Comment: Welcome to SO ! DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: sure i have uploaded the app format class, please help me now

Comment: whenever i tries to post pictures here , it was automatically converted into lines of code instead of code snippet